# Is there training offered for those interested in being moderators?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

Is there training offered for being a moderator? I would love to be one of them. I like learning and helping too.

Answer (score 1):

What channel would you like to be a moderator of? Eg web forums, Telegram, user/tech support, discord, github, catalyst etc

With stackexchange you can start answering questions and helping out right away. As you gain more reputation points for helping out then more options/access becomes available to you.

A lot of information will need to be self-taught via official blogs, and community websites/channels.

I suggest that you start with the IOG technical discord server and find the area of interest to you and expand out from there.

IOG Technical Discord = https://discord.gg/SNvzGjAj

There are also IOG/IOHK blogs (https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/page-1/) and email newletters for the different areas eg community@iohk.io sends out updates relating to stake pool operator interests.

Take a look at the IOG blogs and then you can pick an area of interest to sign up to and then approach them to get more involved.

Comment: Thanks. Am interested in plutus